# Migrate PoIs from a 2D Leaflet map to an Augmented Reality UI?

Tags: android, json, augmented-reality

I have an array of JSON real Points of Interest that came from an API (generated by Java) taken from a PostgreSQL database:

```
[
    {
        "code": 18554,
        "lat": 43.36161686223077,
        "lon": 3.15837302430637,
        "taxon": {
            "popularNameEN": "Moon trefoil",
            "media": {
                "thumbnail": "//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/81/Cistus_creticus_1.jpg/240px-Moon_trefoil.jpg"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "code": 13826,
        "lat": 42.36162882111323,
        "lon": 3.158355343054932,
        "taxon": {
            "popularNameEN": "Rock rose",
            "media": {
                "thumbnail": "//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cc/Cistus_creticus_RJB2.JPG/240px-Cistus_creticus_RJB2.JPG"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

(16000 PoI in an area of 14 hectares).

Currently my app draw them in a 2d regular map (with Leaflet) with the name and a thumbnail (I already have a function that show just the 8 closest, not all 16000).

I want to show same information in a simple and easy Augmented Reality way in Android phones.

I don't care if the result is not perfect because the compass, or anything. I care to use 100% free and open source software and avoid to use an external API, if it is possible. I need just something simple for a show to my client but maybe also something enough good to continue improving my app in the future. What framework/libraries should I use for this and how?

Answer (score 0):

You can start with Google's AR kit.
https://developers.google.com/ar

It is easy and self-explanatory, but for now, it has limited support for devices.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not what I need. After taking a look, if I understood well: Google's AR kit is proprietary software[1](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/downloads)[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_augmented_reality_software#Proprietary) and needs an external API for use it. As I said I just want to do something simple with free and open source software.